# Create item in Ruby DB through form submission

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, controllers

I'm new to Ruby and back-end programming, and am trying to build my first app. What I'm trying to do is create an HTML form that stores the submitted data into a database. I have everything finished, and when I click the submit button on my form it triggers the correct controller, but I'm hitting this error:

> NameError in SubmissionsController#create
>
> undefined local variable or method `title' for #
>   Rails.root: /home/tom/brain_db
>
> Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
>   app/controllers/submissions_controller.rb:4:in `create'
>   Request
>
> Parameters:
>
> {"title"=>"fsdf",
>    "content"=>"fsdfsd"}

And here is my SubmissionsController:

```
class SubmissionsController < ApplicationController

def create 
    Submission.where(title: title).first_or_create(
        title: title,
        content: title
        )
end

def index
    render json: Submission.all
end

def show 
    render json: Submission.find(params[:id])
end


end
```

The problem is that I don't know how to connect my "create" action with the submitted data. The data is correctly sending the back-end in JSON, and in the create action if I changed where(title: title) to where(title: "title") and so on it saves the item into the database properly, but obviously I want to be saving the data from the form. Any advice on this for a Ruby novice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data of the submitted form is accessible in the `params` "hash" inside the controller:

```
def create 
    Submission.where(title: params[:title]).first_or_create(
        title: params[:title],
        content: params[:content]
        )
end
```